# std::map multi-thread reading

Tags: c++, dictionary, thread-safety, std

I have an std::map that can be read from several threads but only one thread writes to it. No elements are ever deleted from it from anywhere. Is it thread-safe or should I use locks for reading-writing operations?

Comment: You need locks. Any thread performing a read could coincide with a write, and give you some crazy garbage results.

Comment: Does writing occur all the time or is writing batched? If it is batched then you may want to consider joining all the worker threads before updating the map and spawning them again after instead of using locks at every read and write operation.

Comment: Interesting a bit related answer despite vector in question also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937079/crash-happens-when-multi-threaded-debug-mtd-is-set-c